# CRM 2016 Email Router: Can not configure

Tags: email, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I cannot configure CRM 2016 Email Router:
When I click on "New Deployment Profile" or "New Configuration Profile" this error message comes (part of it):

> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Management.SecurityManager' threw an exception.
>
> System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
>
> ************** Loaded Assemblies **************
>   mscorlib
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
>
> Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Management
>       Assembly Version: 8.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 8.1.0.359
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20CRM%20Email/Service/Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Email.Management.exe

I checked config files, access rights. It is CRM 2016 Service Pack 1.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the image for installing the email-router had errors. After downloading the setup separately, it worked out fine.